# Thymeleaf upgrade to version 3 not working with thymeleaf-layout-dialect 1.3.2

Tags: layout, thymeleaf

I am trying to upgrade thymeleaf to version 3 but unfortunatelly it is not working with layout dialect. Is there any solution to get i work?

Thank you

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.BETA01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/dom/Attribute
at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect.<clinit>(LayoutDialect.groovy:49) ~[thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.3.2.jar:na]
```

Comment: You better stay in the current stable version of Thymeleaf :  2.1.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

The Dialect API has been rewritten for Thymeleaf 3.  It's still in beta and not all dialects have been migrated yet.

"...not all Thymeleaf dialects have been migrated to Thymeleaf 3 at this stage, so if you are using some external dialects they may not work with Thymeleaf 3. Please check if the required dialects have a Thymeleaf 3 compatible version." (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html)

It appears that progress is underway on a compatible version: https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/tree/dev

It's not on Maven Central, so, if you want to give it a go, you'll need to clone and build it yourself, or use https://jitpack.io/ to get it.  If using jitpack, add

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>dev-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I didn't test that config, but it should be close.

Obviously, this is a snapshot version, under development, and you should carefully consider whether to use it in a production system.